# How do I set the text align indicator in C# WinForm Custom UserControls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, alignment

Using: C# .NET 4.0 Winforms - Visual C# Express 2008

.NET default controls have a pink line in designer mode that allows you to align the text within controls.  E.g. a label and textbox can align text vertically when placed by aligning to the pink line even though they have different heights.

When I make custom controls however, it only allows me to align to the borders.  How do I set the text line position to allow them to be aligned like above?

I couldn't find any web resources on this, probably because I don't know the technical term for these alignment guides.

Comment: They are called snaplines.  It requires creating your own designer.  Sample control + designer [is here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/29e9baf9-3724-4e6c-931d-7cfb00d50c71/)

Answer (score 1):

They are called *snaplines*. It requires creating your own designer. Sample control + designer [is here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/29e9baf9-3724-4e6c-931d-7cfb00d50c71/).